# How do I find out which software/packages are installed from the date of installation of ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, uninstall, re-installation

I am about to uninstall Ubuntu entirely and reinstall a fresh copy. Before I do that I want to make a list of software/package that I have installed so far. Any way to list out?

### Update:

The answer by [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/a/133131/49715) shows how to get the list of **all the packages** from the time when Ubuntu came and directly installs the packages if they are not present but I want to get the list only; not want to install.

Comment: Use your imagination :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dpkg --get-selections > installed-software
```

creates a text file named `installed-software` with all installed software. Move that file to a backup.

```
dpkg --set-selections < installed-software
deselect
```

will install all the packages that have not been installed (in case you want to install them)

If you want to make a list of the differences you make another file after you installed Ubuntu again:

```
dpkg --get-selections > installed-software_new
```

and you can `diff` the 2 files.

If you installed the same version Ubuntu the result should be a list of packages from the old version that was not installed in the new version. Newer Ubuntu will have other package versions so it will not work.

Comment: Not exactly what I want.  **a)** I don't want to install those packages, I just want to list them.  **b)** Your method list all the packages from the time Ubuntu was made. I only want to see from the time it was installed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this instead: if you like to backup/restore all your apps, you could try AptOnCd from Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

There is a full list in the **manifest** file of each distribution at http://releases.ubuntu.com

To get just the list use

```
source /etc/lsb-release
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/$DISTRIB_CODENAME/ubuntu-$DISTRIB_RELEASE-desktop-amd64.manifest \
     -q -O - | cut -f 1 > packages.manifest.list
# compare it with the list generated by 
dpkg --get-selections  | cut -f 1 > packages.installed.list
# from moreutils you can use combine:
combine packages.installed.list not packages.manifest.list > packages.diff.list
```

for 32 bit use another manifest:

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/$DISTRIB_CODENAME/ubuntu-$DISTRIB_RELEASE-desktop-i386.manifest -q -O - | cut -f 1 > packages.manifest.list
```